# save the json post value to send to another function in php

Tags: php, json, function, codeigniter

I have a form that when submit it send to 2 places one is php function and other to json, the reason is there is tag fields that i have to get there values is by json.

The problem is that the json array values going to different table in mysql and needs the id from the other php function. and always gave me `Undefined index: elements`

## Code HTML:

here the form go to function `cadastro_fornecedor()`

```
<form id='form_c_fornecedor' action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/cadastro_fornecedor';?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">adicionar</button>
</form>
```

## Code JS:

here the form when submit colect the values im elements var and post them to `get_value_fornecedor()` and its working fine until here.

```
$('#form_c_fornecedor').bind('submit', function (d) {
    var elements = $('#try').tagHandler('getTags'); 
    $.post("<?php echo base_url().'admin/get_value_fornecedor/'; ?>",{elements: JSON.stringify(elements)});
});
```

## Function `get_value_fornecedor`:

the function received the value with success.

```
public function get_value_fornecedor(){
    $elements = json_decode($_POST['elements'], true);
    return $elements;
}
```

## Function `cadastro_fornecedor`:

Here that I receiving the error that `Undefined index: elements` thats mean the `$elements` value did not pass to this function.

```
public function cadastro_fornecedor(){
    $elements = $this->get_value_fornecedor();

    $inputall= $this->input->post();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome_fantasia', 'Nome Fantasia', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'O campo Nome é obrigatório.');
    }else{
        if($_POST){
            $data_cad = date('Y-m-d');
            $data=array('desc_entidade' =>$inputall['desc_entidade'],
                        'data_cad'      =>$data_cad
                    );
            $id= $this->cake->c_fornecedor($data);

            if(!empty($elements)){
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++){
                    $data_produtos=array(   'fornecedor_id'    =>$id,
                                            'produto_tag'      =>$elements[$i]
                                    );
                    $this->cake->c_produto($data_produtos);
                }
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'O campo Nome é obrigatório.');
            //redirect(base_url().'admin/c_fornecedor');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined 'index' elements is what you get when you try to access the $_POST superglobal. It has nothing to do with your cad.astro_fornecedor function. The problem is at your get_value_fornecedor function.

Comment: `get_value_fornecedor` function received the value normally ... the problem happens wen I pass this value from `get_value_fornecedor` to `cadastro_fornecedor`.

Comment: You are calling the function in cadastro_fornecedor and that is why you get the error then. Try var_dumping $_POST in cadastro_fornecedor and see what you have.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for trying to help ... solved by Akshay suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are posting data to method `get_value_fornecedor` but you are not saving it anywhere, make use of codeigniter session

First you have load session library.

```
$this->load->library("session");
```

You can load it in auto load, which I think is better.

To set session

```
$this->session->set_userdata("SESSION_NAME","VALUE");
```

To extract Data

```
$this->session->userdata("SESSION_NAME");
```

You can rewrite your function like below

```
public function get_value_fornecedor()
{
    /* This is for your ajax call for saving data inside session where key somedata*/
    if(isset($_POST['elements']))
    {
            $this->session->set_userdata("somedata",$_POST['elements']);
    }else
    {
           /* This is for accessing your saved data */
            $elements_saved = $this->session->userdata("somedata");

            if($elements_saved)
            {
                  $elements = json_decode($elements_saved, true);
                  return $elements; 
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give you feedback later .. checking it!

Comment: @MinaMagdy: sure

Comment: Thank you friend .. work as rock .. I did not remember to use set_userdata() .. really thank you!!!